# Can the Taylor remainder be bounded from below?

Tags: real-analysis

I know this sounds stupid, let me explain myself.

Obviously if the function is a polynomial, at some degree the remainder will be identically equal to 0. I can see that. So my question is the following.

If $f(x)$ is a smooth function and the remainder does not become identically 0 at any order and fixing $N$ we have

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0)x^n+r_N(x).$$

Does there exists an integer $m$ such that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{m}}{r_N(x)}=0?$$

It will actually be enough for me if there exists an integer $m$ and a real $c$ such that $r(x)>cx^m$.